# django html query set to one string

Tags: django

I have a query set and i wants each string/item display in a class name

for example :

queryset = models.ManyToManyField(classTag, blank=True);

what I tired:

```
<div class="queryset.all()"><h4>student1</h4></div>
```

what I got:

```
<div class="<QuerySet [<classTag: English>, <classTag: Math>, <classTag: CS>]>"><h4>student1</h4></div>
```

what I want:

```
<div class="English Math CS"><h4>student1</h4></div>
```

Comment: Can you share your models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<div class="{% for i in queryset.all() %} {{i}} {% endfor %}"><h4>student1</h4></div>
```

Then you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop in your template to get tags of classname that are present in queryset

Comment: <div class="{{% for loop goes here ?%}}><h4>student1</h4></div>